# Calculating the sum of values of a map in Java 8 stream which can contain invalid numbers

Tags: java, java-8

I have a map: `Map<String, Map<String, String>> x`

I want to calculate the sum of values in my second map for this:

```
x.values().stream().mapToDouble(y -> Double.parse(y.get("myKey"))).sum();
```

However if y.get("myKey") is not a valid number it will throw an error as expected...is there a way I can avoid it and pass only valid numbers

I see that Doubles.tryParse from guava library is there which will return null incase it is not parsable. But I am not able to figure out how I can use that to sum only the valid numbers.

Comment: If you use guava Doubles.tryParse in the map, you can follow it up with a filter where not null.  Then sum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to use third-party libraries, just catch the `NumberFormatException`:

```
double sum = x.values().stream().mapToDouble(y -> {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(y.get("myKey"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0.0;
    }
}).sum();
```

You can also just catch `RuntimeException` if a *missing* value should be ignored, instead of causing `NullPointerException`.

Comment: My main objection to this is the readability, which you could easily fix by extracting the logic to a utility class. I think this is much cleaner: `x.values().stream().mapToDouble(Numbers::parseDoubleOrDefault).sum()`

Answer (score 5):

`Doubles.tryParse()` returns null if it fails. Here's how you can use that to your advantage:

```
x.values()
    .stream()
    .map(y -> Doubles.tryParse(y.get("myKey")))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)  // exclude invalid numbers
    .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
    .sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

These avoid raising/catching the exception by pre-filtering with RegEx (I would probably do this for ints, but on reflection ***I'm not sure this is sensible for doubles*** due to the format complexity).

Don't mind raising exceptions? See: [#45873009](http://#45873009)
Using Guava already? See: [#45873075](http://#45873075)

## 1. filter() String then map()

```
x.values()
    .stream()
    .map(m -> m.get("myKey"))
    .filter(s -> s.matches(Numbers.DOUBLE_FORMAT)) // you'll want a constant...
    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
    .sum();
```

## 2. Utility and default value

```
x.values()
    .stream()
    .map(m -> m.get("myKey"))
    .mapToDouble(Numbers::parseDoubleOrDefault) // default 0.0 doesn't affect sum...
    .sum();
```

## 3. Utility and flatMap()

```
x.values()
    .stream()
    .map(m -> m.get("myKey"))
    .flatMapToDouble(Numbers::tryParseDouble)
    .sum();
```

## ...and here is the utility class

```
public class Numbers {

    // Extensive regex! Thank you @Andreas & Oracle Docs
    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-
    private static final String DIGITS = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
    private static final String HEX_DIGITS = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";
    private static final String EXPONENT = "[eE][+-]?"+ DIGITS;
    public static final String DOUBLE_FORMAT = "[\\x00-\\x20]*[+-]?(NaN|Infinity|((("+ DIGITS +"(\\.)?("+ DIGITS +"?)("+ EXPONENT +")?)|(\\.("+ DIGITS +")("+ EXPONENT +")?)|(((0[xX]" + HEX_DIGITS + "(\\.)?)|(0[xX]" + HEX_DIGITS + "?(\\.)" + HEX_DIGITS + "))[pP][+-]?" + DIGITS + "))[fFdD]?))[\\x00-\\x20]*";

    public double parseDoubleOrDefault(final String input, final double defaultValue) {
        return input.matches(DOUBLE_FORMAT)
            ? Double.parseDouble(input)
            : defaultValue;
    }

    public double parseDoubleOrDefault(final String input) {
        return parseDoubleOrDefault(0.0);
    }

    // Stream because Java 8 flatMap doesn't work on Optional
    public DoubleStream tryParseDouble(final String input) {
        return input.matches(DOUBLE_FORMAT)
            ? DoubleStream.of(Double.parseDouble(input))
            : DoubleStream.empty();
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want to ignore the perfectly valid value `0.25`? And `-42`? And `1e-10`? Just to give a few examples of valid `double` values.

Comment: @Andreas - Ahh sorry, I copied my int code not double! I'll update the match.

Comment: You are still ignoring `1e-10`. To validate `double` values, you need regex defined in the javadoc of [`Double.valueOf(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-). Which is kind of overkill, since it's easier to just [catch the `NumberFormatException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873009/5221149).

Comment: Strange to use a `DoubleStream` for a single value. I would return 0 or an `OptionalDouble`.

Comment: @Andreas - According to my editor `1e-10` is a match for the double format I posted (about 9m before your comment). I'm generally not a fan of raising and catching exceptions to manage normal (non-exceptional) behaviour... but the required regex at that link is making me reconsider :/ Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @shmosel - OptionalDouble doesn't flatmap (as of Java 8)

Comment: You can with Guava's `Streams::stream`, or you can `.filter(OptionalDouble::isPresent).map(OptionalDouble::get)` or `.map(o -> o.orElse(0))`.

Comment: I think if people have Guava then your answer is the way to go. I prefer to use the `XStream`/`Stream<X>` types than impose `filter()` then `map()` (and suspect there is no/minimal overhead doing so; though I'd be interested if that's true). Thanks for the edit (missing bracket fix) btw!

Comment: I only brought up Guava because OP explicitly said he's using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152804/discussion-between-codeconfident-and-shmosel).